# Hiding SoftKeyboard not working in Android 9.0 Pie

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I had this code for hiding soft keyboard in android:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine for other Android version except Android 9.0. In Android 9.0, it has no effect and soft keyboard is not hiding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `getCurrentFocus()` is returning null even though editText had focused. Hence no window token and we cannot hide keyboard without it.

Here is the fix:

```
public void hideKeyboard() {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (manager != null) {
            manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

we are getting window token from `android.R.id.content` rather than getting it from currentFocused View. hence this works like a charm.